# Show that there's a solution to $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod {p^2}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

> Show that there's a solution to $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod {p^2}$ where $p$ is a prime such that $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$

Formalizing it using Jacobi symbol we want to show that $\left(\frac{-1}{p^2}\right) = 1$ and indeed:

$$ \left(\frac{-1}{p^2}\right) = \left(\frac{-1}{p}\right) \cdot \left(\frac{-1}{p}\right) = \left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)^2=1$$

I didn't use the fact that $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$.

Is my proof correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Jacobi symbol doesn't tell us that the top number is or is not a quadratic residue.  Your calculation is correct, but the fact that $\left(\frac{-1}{p^2}\right) = 1$ doesn't imply that $-1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p^2.$
For example, take $p=7$.  $-1$ is a QNR mod $7$, so $\left(\frac{-1}{7}\right) = -1.$  So the Jacobi symbol $\left(\frac{-1}{7^2}\right) = 1.$  But if $x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{7^2}$ has a solution, then that solution would work modulo $7$ too.

Instead, note that $p^2$ must have a primitive root $r$ whose order is $p(p-1)$.  Since $p\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, then the order is a multiple of $4$, say $p(p-1)=4k$.  Then, with a little work, you can show $(r^k)^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{p^2}$.

Comment: I see. I totally forgot that a result of $1$ tells us nothing

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution is to note that $U(p^2)$ is a cyclic group of order $p(p-1)$, a multiple of $4$. Therefore, there is an element $u$ of order $4$. Then $u^2=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

No, your proof is incorrect because you're assuming that $\left(\dfrac{a}{n}\right)=1$ iff $a$ is a quadratic residue modulo $n$

This is true in case of the Legendre symbol when the denominator is an odd prime but not for the Jacobi symbol.

> **Quoting from Wikipedia:**
>
> But, unlike the Legendre symbol:
>
> If (a/n) = 1 then a may or may not be a quadratic residue modulo n.

The correct way would be to show that $-1$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$ since $\left(\dfrac{-1}p\right)=(-1)^{(p-1)/2}=1$ since $p\equiv 1\pmod4$, thus $(p-1)/2$ is even.

Now, use Hensel's lifting lemma to show that $-1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p^2$.

You can also generalize this to higher powers of $p$, i.e., $-1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p^k~\forall~k\geq 2$ using Hensel's lemma (or induction, which mimics the proof of Hensel's lemma, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/223430/relationship-between-quadratic-residues-modulo-a-prime-and-quadratic-residues-mo))